# SignalR client side (Blazor) method does not received accurate parameter from the hub

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, blazor-server-side

I am new to SignalR and Blazor Server. As a learning exercise, I am building a real-time TicTacToe game. All code is [open-source and on GitHub](https://github.com/jwankhalaf-cx/tictacgo/blob/feat/10-disable-ability-to-make-a-move-for-player-awaiting-turn/UI/Hubs/GameHub.cs).

I am having an issue.

When my Hub method makes a call to the Blazor client-side method, the parameter I pass doesn't arrive as it should.

**CODE:**

Here are the `OnInitializedAsync`, `MakeMove` and `CanMakeMove` methods on my `Game.razor` file along. Not the `RenderGame` game method.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
  _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri($"/gamehub/{GameCode}"))
    .Build();

  _hubConnection.On<Models.Game>("RenderGame", game =>
  {
    _gameBoard = game.GetBoard();
    _host = game.Host;

    if (game.CanStart())
    {
      _guest = game.Guest;
    }

    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
  });

  await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
}

private async Task MakeMove(Move model)
{
  if (CanMakeMove())
  {
    if (_hubConnection is not null)
    {
      await _hubConnection.SendAsync("MakeMove", GameCode, model);
    }
  }
}

private bool CanMakeMove()
{
  return _host is not null && _guest is not null;
}
```

Here's my complete `GameHub.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using UI.Enums;
using UI.Models;
using UI.Services.Interfaces;

namespace UI.Hubs;

public class GameHub : Hub
{
  private readonly IGameEngineService _gameEngineService;

  public GameHub(IGameEngineService gameEngineService)
  {
    _gameEngineService = gameEngineService;
  }

  public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"OnConnectedAsync fired, Client Connection Id is: {Context.ConnectionId}");

    if (Context.GetHttpContext()?.GetRouteValue("GameCode") is string gameCode)
    {
      bool gameExists = _gameEngineService.GameExists(gameCode);

      if (gameExists)
      {
        Player guest = new()
        {
          ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId,
          Name = "Emma",
          ImageUrl = "https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/12/Avatar-Profile-PNG-Images-HD.png",
          Mark = Marks.O,
          HasTurn = false
        };

        _gameEngineService.JoinGame(gameCode, guest);
      }
      else
      {
        Player host = new()
        {
          ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId,
          Name = "Dan",
          ImageUrl = "https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/12/Avatar-Profile-Vector.png",
          Mark = Marks.X,
          HasTurn = true
        };

        _gameEngineService.StartGame(gameCode, host);
      }

      Game? game = _gameEngineService.GetGame(gameCode);

      if (game is not null)
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("RenderGame", game);
      else
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ShowError", "game not found");

      await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
  }

  public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception? exception)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"OnDisconnectedAsync fired, Client Connection Id is: {Context.ConnectionId}");

    if (Context.GetHttpContext()?.GetRouteValue("GameCode") is string gameCode)
    {
      _gameEngineService.LeaveGame(gameCode, Context.ConnectionId);

      await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
  }

  public async Task MakeMove(string gameCode, Move model)
  {
    Game? game = _gameEngineService.MakeMove(gameCode, model);

    if (game is not null) await Clients.All.SendAsync("RenderGame", game);
  }
}
```

**ISSUE:**

when I make a move, the `MakeMove` get fired on the Client, which in turn calls the `MakeMove` on the Hub. The Hub, then registers the move against the `game` object, and retrieves the game to send back to the client.

The method calls occur (I hit them with my debug points), but the `game` parameter that arrived to the `RenderGame` on the client side is different from what was sent from the backend.

Hopefully, these screenshots will help:

Here's the hub with its debug point hit, notice how the `game._gameBoard` has an `X` at index `0`.

[image: hub screenshot]

Here's a screenshot from the `RenderGame` method, notice how now the `X` is no longer there!

[image: blazor component]

I'm really confused as to where I'm going wrong with this. I've tried to follow the [official docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server).

Comment: I am using vs2022, and can't reproduce the issue when using the repo, [pls check my gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A7uS.gif).

Comment: I saw you have made some change in your current project, right? If we need to find out the reason, we need more details.

Answer (score 0):

In your code , you are missing this

```
Game gameDto = _gameMapper.Convert(game);
```

From the repo, I found

```
public async Task MakeMove(string gameCode, Move model)
{
    Entities.Game? game = _gameEngineService.MakeMove(gameCode, model);

    if (game is not null)
    {
      Game gameDto = _gameMapper.Convert(game);

      await Clients.All.SendAsync("RenderGame", gameDto);
    }
}
```

Please make sure you want pass `game` or `gameDto` object.

**It works well in my side.**

[image]

Comment: Since posting the question, I figured out the problem. It turns out I can't send complex classes from the Hub to the Client. By "complex" I mean, classes that contain method and logic, like my `Entities.Game` class. However, I can send DTO classes, this is why I've created `Models.Game` which is a simple DTO and send that to the client instead. Now all works. Thanks